# Pandas dataframe: How to sort groups by the earliest time of a group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a pandas way to solve the following problem? There is a dataframe with many columns including 'time' and 'eventid'. First I want to group the dataframe by 'eventid'. Each 'eventid' may linked with multiple 'time'. Then I need to sort the 'eventid' groups by the earliest 'time' of each group (order inside a group is not important). For example, my input is like this:

| eventid | time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9:10 |
| 2 | 9:20 |
| 1 | 9:30 |
| 3 | 9:40 |
| 3 | 9:50 |
| 2 | 9:00 |

my desired output is like this:

| eventid | time |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 9:00 |
| 2 | 9:20 |
| 1 | 9:30 |
| 1 | 9:10 |
| 3 | 9:50 |
| 3 | 9:40 |

I have tried `df.sort_values(by=['time','eventid'])` and `df.groupby` but may be wrong for this situation. Another way is to sort by 'time' and then query and rewrite the dataframe. But it will take too much time since the original data is quite big.

I couldn't find a similar question before. Thanks a lot for possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can group by the eventid and get first(min) time as group value.
will get data like this

```
            time
eventid 
1           9:10
2           9:00
3           9:40
```

then we merge to dataframe,and sort by the grouped time

```py
groups = df.groupby('eventid').min('time')
df = df.merge(groups,on='eventid',suffixes=('','_right'))
df = df.sort_values('time_right')
```

```
    eventid time    time_right
2   2       9:20    9:00
3   2       9:00    9:00
0   1       9:10    9:10
1   1       9:30    9:10
4   3       9:40    9:40
5   3       9:50    9:40
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! These codes do work. However, my 'time' column has the datetime type so there is still some problem with the df.min() function. I think I can fix it out.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
df.sort_values(['time'],ascending=True).groupby('event_id')
```

This code sorts the values of time column first and then groups the dataframe based on "event_id". It works only if there time column ranges from one timestamp to "n" timestamps. If there is a min timestamp in each "event_id", I think user @nay's answer is right.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: yeah definitely...I will from here on...I didn't try the code but since the question was relatively easier thought the answer would work, anyway the OP says that @nay's answer is working fine. Thank you.