# Reindex kmeans clustered dataframe in an ascending order values

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I have created a set of 4 clusters using kmeans, but I'd like to reorder the clusters in an ascending manner to have a predictable way of outputting an analysis every time the script is executed.

The resulting df with the clusters is something like:

```
           customer_id  recency  frequency  monetary_value  recency_cluster  \
0    44792907512250289       21          1           43.76                0   
1  4277896431638207047      443          1           73.13                1   
2  1509512561185834874      559          1           37.50                1   
3 -8259919882769629944      437          1           34.38                1   
4  8269311313560571571      133          2          324.78                0   
5  6521698907264712834      311          1            6.32                3   
6  9102795320443090762      340          1          174.99                3   
7  6203217338400763719       39          1           77.50                0   
8  7633758030510673403      625          1           95.26                2   
9 -2417721548925747504      644          1           76.84                2   

   frequency_cluster  monetary_value_cluster  
0                  1                       0  
1                  1                       0  
2                  1                       0  
3                  1                       0  
4                  0                       1  
5                  1                       0  
6                  1                       1  
7                  1                       0  
8                  1                       0  
9                  1                       0
```

The recency clusters are not sorted by the data, I'd like for example that the recency cluster 0 to be the one with the min value = 1.0 (recency cluster 1).

```
recency_cluster  count      mean        std         min     25%     50%     75%     max                         
0                17609.0    700.900960  56.895995   609.0   651.0   697.0   749.0   807.0
1                16458.0    102.692672  62.952229   1.0     47.0    101.0   159.0   210.0
2                17166.0    515.971746  56.592490   418.0   466.0   517.0   567.0   608.0
3                18634.0    317.599227  58.852980   211.0   269.0   319.0   367.0   416.0
```

Using something like:

```
rfm_df.groupby('recency_cluster')['recency'].transform('min')
```

Will return a colum with the min value of each clusters

```
0          1
1        418
2        418
3        418
4          1
        ... 
69862    609
69863      1
69864    211
69865    609
69866    211
```

I guess there's got to be a way to convert this categories [1,211,418,609] into [0, 1, 2, 3] in order to get the desired result but I can't come up with a solution.

Or maybe there's a better approach to the problem.

Edit: I did this and I think it's working:

```
rfm_df['recency_normalized_cluster'] = rfm_df.groupby('recency_cluster')['recency'].transform('min').astype('category').cat.codes
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe: How to sort groups by the earliest time of a group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68250141/pandas-dataframe-how-to-sort-groups-by-the-earliest-time-of-a-group)

Answer (score 0):

```
rfm_df['recency_normalized_cluster'] = rfm_df.groupby('recency_cluster')['recency'].transform('min').astype('category').cat.codes
```